# Adjective/Noun usage with "get" in the sentence

Tags: verbs

From the below sentences, which one is correct?

Primary school teacher **gets award**.

or

Primary school teacher **get awarded**.

Please give justification, if possible.

Thanks,

Charmi

Comment: Is this a news headline? That's how it reads. In headlines they reduce the content to the most base info and avoid using "the" and "a/an".

Comment: In your second sentence it has to have **gets** to be grammatical. Yes **get** is in that sense a copular verb. Grammatical as that sentence is, it sounds strange. Noone probably use it to mean what your first sentence mean.

Comment: @Man_From_India Awarded should also answer "awarded with what"... "Primary school teacher gets awarded the teacher of the year medallion"... for example.

Comment: @Catija *nods*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

> Primary school teacher gets award

if you are saying the receives a physical object that is an award.

Or:

> Primary school teacher gets awarded

if you are saying that the teacher undergoes a process that results in him/her becoming awarded, as a status.

Most of the time, when one gets awarded, you receive something that is a reward, so usually the distinction is not important and you probably don't have to worry about which one to say too much.